# Achieve multiple rows in gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to get the layout as in the gif below  but could not get any resource to continue with. There are two rows with multiple columns and is scrollable. How can I achieve such layout?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question says, you follow this approach, and it is not containing `multiple columns`, items are having different width. This snippet will work fine.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    key: const ValueKey("row1"),
                    children: _items(),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    key: const ValueKey("row2"),
                    children: _items(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: how to handle it if the data are from same array?

Comment: you can split the list  like for 1st part `items.sublist(0, items.length ~/ 2)` and second row `items.sublist(( items.length ~/ 2), items.length)`

Comment: Help me with this also please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302909/pin-the-layout-below-and-start-scrolling-at-certain-position-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `SingleChildScrolView` widget with `axis : horizontal`  and that listitem will be created using `FilterChip` widget.

like this :

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                child:  Wrap(
                                  spacing: 10.0,
                                  runSpacing: 5.0,
                                  children: [...generateTags()],
                                ),
                              ),






 generateTags(){
    return _keywords.map((e) => FilterChip(label : e)).toList();
  }



var _keywords =["hello" , "hi" ,"words 1" , "word 2"];
```

Comment: I could achieve what you have suggested but my question is different. I want to show the list items values in 2 rows with multiple columns as in gif mentioned